# Where should I use $templateCache?

Tags: angularjs, angular-templatecache

I want to use $templateCache service to add some html into the cache. In Angular documentation example, it only shows the case of using it in run:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.run(function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put('templateId.html', 'This is the content of the template');
});
```

However, when I am trying to add some templates through myApp config, there seems to be injector error. Is there a way to use templateCache not in RUN?

Thanks

Comment: Are you 100% positive that you cannot inject $templateCache in config? What's the injector error?

Comment: Its the Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error

Comment: @mostruash $templateCache is a service and cannot be injected into config. You can inject providers only.

Comment: @hansmaad, so only factories may be injected into the config?

Comment: @uksz providers. Why do you want to add templates in `config`? What's wrong with `run`?

Comment: Oh that makes sense. It was more intuitive for me to include it in config ;) But I guess I was wrong, becasue Run gets executed before config, is that right?

Comment: `config` is used to configure services (using their providers). They will be created after `config` and then available in `run`. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#provider-recipe

Comment: Please see this link to add items dynamically into templateCache http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/10/01/angularjs-partials-lazy-prefetching-strategy-weighted-directed-graph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`run` is the correct place to use the `$templateCache`. Since `$templateCache` is a service, it's not accessible in the configuration phase, because it hasn't been created yet. `config` is used to configure services (like `$templateCache`) using their providers. You can only inject providers to `config`.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that, most of the time, you shouldn't be writing code that accesses `$templateCache` directly at all. What you should be doing is using a build system such as `gulp` and a plugin such as `gulp-angular-templatecache`.

Then your templates are simply a bunch of `.html` files, your editor recognises them as html and does the appropriate linting while you edit, and all you have to do is ensure your app declares a dependency on the template module.

So the code you gave above would become:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myappTemplates']);
```

and the use of `$templateCache` inside `.run()` is pushed down to automatically generated code that you never see.